# How to change the text and icon color of selected menu item on Navigation Drawer programmatically using java

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am a beginner in Android Development. Using android's default Navigation drawer activity I am developing an application. One of the requirements of this app is to change the background colors of layouts (including navigation drawer header color) randomly at run time.

Now everything is going fine except the color of the selected menu item on navigation drawer is still **blue**. like this :

[image]

**Now what I want is as the background color of other layouts is pink the selected menu item on the navigation bar should also be pink (I mean the text color and the icon should be pink) like this :**

[image]

**Can anyone please tell how to achieve it programatically in code as I have to change selected text and icon colors at runtime randomly.**

Here's the menu xml file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_quiz_all"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_public_black_24dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:title="All Countries Quiz"/>
        <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_quiz_bookmarked"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
                android:title="Favorite Quiz"/>
    </group>


    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_rate"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
                android:title="Rate this app"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
                android:title="Share"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_feedback"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_feedback_black_24dp"
                android:title="Feedback"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_about"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
                android:title="About"/>
        </menu>
    </item>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="Settings"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly thank you all for responding back with your solutions :) Learning from the answers above and doing some research on `ColorStateList` I finally managed to create a `method` which sets the color of the checked item on the navigation drawer to match the color of my app theme color which is generated randomly at runtime.

**Here's the method:**

```
public void setNavMenuItemThemeColors(int color){
    //Setting default colors for menu item Text and Icon
    int navDefaultTextColor = Color.parseColor("#202020");
    int navDefaultIconColor = Color.parseColor("#737373");

    //Defining ColorStateList for menu item Text
    ColorStateList navMenuTextList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled},
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused},
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}
            },
            new int[] {
                    color,
                    navDefaultTextColor,
                    navDefaultTextColor,
                    navDefaultTextColor,
                    navDefaultTextColor
            }
    );

    //Defining ColorStateList for menu item Icon
    ColorStateList navMenuIconList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled},
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused},
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}
            },
            new int[] {
                    color,
                    navDefaultIconColor,
                    navDefaultIconColor,
                    navDefaultIconColor,
                    navDefaultIconColor
            }
    );

    mNavView.setItemTextColor(navMenuTextList);
    mNavView.setItemIconTintList(navMenuIconList);
}
```

you can call this method with any `int color` you want :)

Comment: Great explanation

Comment: Good one, Thanks

Answer (score 58):

First check for the NavigationView below

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item_color"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Check here two things

```
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item_color"
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item_color"
```

These both tags are using `drawer_item_color.xml` which is a selector in drawable folder and below is the code for it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/pink" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

use selector and add colors you want. This will do the job for you.

Comment: Selectors are generally the way to go with this sort of thing...  but he wants to make "random" color changes...  that needs to be addressed in the activity code...  thumbs up anyway for the all out explanation

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination Abid :) but the thing is I want to do all this using java at runtime. My app changes its theme color randomly at runtime, so I need to change the selected menu item text and icon color at runtime to match the theme color. Any ideas how to achieve it at runtime uisng java ?

Comment: Good explanation, but app:itemIconTint() not accessing drawable resources, its only accessing colors.

Answer (score 16):

**First Way**

try using:

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/color_pink"  //selected icon color
app:itemTextColor="@color/color_pink" //selected text color
app:itemBackground="@color/color_gray"
```

For your `NavigationView`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:headerLayout="@layout/header_layout"
app:itemIconTint="@color/color_pink"  
app:itemTextColor="@color/color_pink" 
app:itemBackground="@color/color_gray"
app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />
```

**Second Way**

For *programetically* change use:

```
navigationView.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList1);
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(ColorStateList2);
```

Define `ColorStateList1` and `ColorStateList2` as:

For Navigation View Item Text Color

```
int[][] state = new int[][] {
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
        new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed

};

int[] color = new int[] {
        Color.WHITE,
        Color.BLUE,
        Color.WHITE,
        Color.WHITE
};

ColorStateList ColorStateList1 = new ColorStateList(state, color);
```

For Navigation View Item Icon Color

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
        new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed

};

int[] colors = new int[] {
        Color.WHITE,
        Color.BLUE,
        Color.WHITE,
        Color.WHITE
};

ColorStateList ColorStateList2 = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
```

Comment: Actually I want to do it at runtime .. any ideas how to do it programatically in java ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit :) .. I am new to android .. it would be great if you could explain the ColorStateList in more detail please ... thumbs up for you answer anyways :)

Comment: Searching on internet I found ColorStateList to be xml resource file having selectors. So I think I need to pre define the colors in xml itself which is not what I want as the colors need to be dynamically changed at runtime. **The colors are randomly generated** :(

Answer (score 4):

I have tested this code on sdk 17 to sdk 26
code write the logic after

```
   setContent(R.layou.your_activity)
```

find the navigation view with Id

```
 private void setupNavigationSelection(NavigationView navigationViewList) {


    /* note : warning don't use other attribute  just checked and unchecked else         wont work*/
    int[][] states = new int[][]{
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, // checked
            new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked} // unchecked
    };
    int[] colors = new int[]{
            Color.RED
            Color.GREEN,
    };

    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = getSideBarDrawable(0x80dedede);
    StateListDrawable arrowImgStates = new StateListDrawable();
    Drawable normalDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);;
    arrowImgStates.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, normalDrawable);
    arrowImgStates.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused}, layerDrawable);
    arrowImgStates.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}, layerDrawable);
    arrowImgStates.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, layerDrawable);
    arrowImgStates.addState(new int[]{}, normalDrawable);

    ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    navigationViewList.setItemTextColor(colorStateList);
    navigationViewList.setItemIconTintList(colorStateList);
    navigationViewList.setItemBackground(arrowImgStates);

}

public LayerDrawable getSideBarDrawable(int bgColor) {
    int iSize = CLViewUtil.dpToPx(6);
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
    gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    gradientDrawable.setStroke(iSize, CLThemeUtil.getThemePrimaryColor(this));
    gradientDrawable.setColor(bgColor);
    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{gradientDrawable});
    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(0, 0, -iSize, -iSize, -iSize);
    return layerDrawable;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
mNavigationView.setItemTextColor(yourColorStateList);
```

Comment: Thans for your answer Silva .. Correct me if I am wrong but I think ColorSateList is a selector xml resource file which requires the color to be pre defined. But in my app colors need to be dynamically changed at runtime. The colors are randomly generated :(