# How do I make a single item in my NavigationDrawer have a different color of text?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I was able to change the color of the emergency icon to red by using this code **navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);** in my Java class. I want to be able to also make the icon be red, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. Here is the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3B0R.png) As you can see the icon is already red but the text isn't. How do I change to word "Emergency Call" from black to Red?

Here is my Themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Flash" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
       
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
       

    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Flash.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance44">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Flash.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.Flash.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

And here is my Java class in where I have used the navigation drawer

```
hamburgerMenuButton = findViewById(R.id.hamburgerMenuIcon);
        hamburgerMenuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            }
        });

        navigationView.bringToFront();
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(Location.this, drawerLayout,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(Location.this);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.emergencyCallNavigationDrawer);
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle());
        s.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(this, R.style.TextAppearance44), 0, s.length(), 0);
        menuItem.setTitle(s);
```

Update this is what happend to my code

[Here is what happend to my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPW4H.png)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42701080/5978440)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the menu item and then set the spannable text with the desired color to achieve this.
This is how I have achieved this:

**MenuItem**

```
Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(id);
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle());
s.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(this, R.style.TextAppearance44), 0, s.length(), 0);
menuItem.setTitle(s);
```

**TextAppearance44**

```
<style name="TextAppearance44">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextView</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_20sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: where did you get the menu.findItem? and do I put the id of the name of the title in the (id)? Sorry I am new in Android Studio

Comment: `R.id.emergencyCallNavigationDrawer` , should work

Comment: how about the .menu? how do I fix this?

Comment: I will edit the question so you could see what I have done

Comment: `Menu menu = navView.getMenu();` , I have updated this in the code

Comment: Oh I will check it

Comment: Check the edit there are still errors :(

Comment: What does error shows?

Comment: java:70: error: method getMenu in class NavigationView cannot be applied to given types;
        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu(R.id.emergencyCallNavigationDrawer);
                                  ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: You have merged the 2 lines.  `Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(id);`  while you are getting id from getMenu() functions